# QDialog not painting in loop

Tags: c++, qt

So I have a QDialog class that's launched from a QMainWindow. The constructor sets up the UI. I declare the object in the QMainWindow, then i call the method that loops in the QDialog class. The result is that when the QDialog is shown(dialog->show() is in the constructor) the window appears without the layout. After the loop completes the layout is then shown.

I've tried using exec() instead, but then the method does not execute until after the dialog is closed.

Comment: What kind of loop? Dialogs can be modal or non-modal, and if they are not blocking, they should run their own event loop internally. If you block that mechanism it may not work properly.

Comment: Maybe try experimenting with placing `qApp->processEvents()` somewhere around the code that creates the dialog and/or runs the loop.

Comment: qApp->processEvents() before calling the method did it. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`qApp->processEvents()` should help you out. Try placing it around the code creating the dialog and/or running the loop.